# A potential new norm for matrices and Horn's inequalities

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, inequalities, convex-analysis, matrix-theory

I am investigating a function defined in terms of the singular values of matrices. Initially, I simplified the problem by focusing on the eigenvalues of $2 \times 2$ Hermitian, positive-definite matrices.

For given $p, q \geq 1$, the function $N_{(p,q)}$ is defined as follows:

$$ N_{(p,q)} (A) := \inf \left\lbrace \epsilon > 0 :\left(\frac{a}{\epsilon}\right)^p + \left(\frac{b}{\epsilon}\right)^q \leq 1 \right\rbrace.$$

Here, $a$ and $b$ denote the singular values of $A$, with $a$ being the largest. How can one show that this function satisfies the triangle inequality?

I am particularly interested in connections to Horn's inequalities, as they concern the singular values of sums of matrices and seem highly relevant to the problem at hand. Furthermore, the underlying function $$\Theta_{(p,q)} (a,b) = a^p + b^q$$ is a convex modular functional, which is pertinent.

I am seeking guidance or references that could provide some insight into this problem. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or does anyone have suggestions on potential approaches?

Comment: This expression is unitarily invariant, but is not a symmetric gauge function of the singular values, hence is not a norm.  See for instance https://nhigham.com/2021/02/02/what-is-a-unitarily-invariant-norm/

Comment: Thank you, @TerryTao. I was led astray by a myriad calculations and have not yet found a counterexample to the triangle inequality. Your explanation and reference have clarified matters for me. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Actually on closer inspection the gauge condition is obeyed for $p \geq q$. See the answer given below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the standard classification of unitarily invariant norms (see e.g., [this blog post](https://nhigham.com/2021/02/02/what-is-a-unitarily-invariant-norm/)), the expression $N_{(p,q)}$ is a norm if and only if the function
$$ \| (x,y) \| := \inf \left\{ \varepsilon > 0: \left(\frac{\max(|x|, |y|)}{\varepsilon}\right)^p + \left(\frac{\min(|x|, |y|)}{\varepsilon}\right)^q \leq 1 \right\}$$
is a norm, or equivalently if the set
$$ S := \{ (x,y): \max(|x|,|y|)^p + \max(|x|,|y|)^q \leq 1 \}$$
is convex (certainly it is symmetric and has non-empty interior).  In the upward sector $\{ (x,y): |x| \leq y \}$, this set is convex from the convexity of $y^p+|x|^q$ already observed by the OP, and at the endpoint $(a,a)$ of the set on the upper right edge of the sector, where $a>0$ is the unique positive solution to the equation $a^p+a^q=1$, implicit differentiation of the condition $y^p + |x|^q = 1$ reveals that the boundary of this set has a slope of $-\frac{q a^{q-1}}{p a^{p-1}}$ at this point, which is less than or equal to $-1$ iff we have the condition
$$ p a^p \geq q a^q. \quad (1)$$
By symmetry along the y-axis,  at the opposite endpoint $(-a,a)$, the slope is at most $+1$ iff the same condition (1) holds.  As $S$ is symmetric across the diagonals $x=y$ and $x=-y$, we conclude that the entire set $S$ is convex iff (1) holds, and so $N_{(p,q)}$ is a matrix norm iff (1) holds also.

To obtain an explicit counterexample to the triangle inequality when (1) fails: observe that $\mathrm{diag}(a,a)$ is in the convex hull of the matrices $\mathrm{diag}(a+\delta,a-\delta)$, $\mathrm{diag}(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ for any $0 < \delta < a$, so by symmetry and the triangle inequality one sees that if one wishes $N_{(p,q)}$ to be a norm, one needs
$$ N_{(p,q)}(\mathrm{diag}(a,a)) \leq N_{(p,q)}(\mathrm{diag}(a+\delta,a-\delta))$$
which is equivalent to
$$ (a+\delta)^p + (a-\delta)^q \geq a^p + a^q = 1.$$
Taking $\delta$ to be small and performing a Taylor expansion, we see that this fails when (1) fails for $\delta$ small enough.

To see when (1) holds, we make the change of variables $a^p = \theta$, $a^q = 1-\theta$ for some $0 < \theta < 1$, then
$$ \frac{p}{q} = \frac{\log \theta}{\log(1-\theta)}$$
and the condition (1) rearranges to
$$ \theta \log \theta \leq (1-\theta) \log (1-\theta).$$
This turns out to hold precisely when $\theta \geq 1/2$, or equivalently $p \geq q$ (the difference $\theta \log \theta - (1-\theta) \log (1-\theta)$ is odd, vanishes at $\theta=1/2,1$, and concave for $1/2 \leq \theta \leq 1$).